# product of sums and other useful indexing tricks

Tags: arithmetic

Can you explain to me the following equalities: 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\left( \sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j) \right)\left( \sum_{k=1}^n (x_i-x_k) \right) \right]= \sum_{i,j,k=1}^n (x_i - x_j)(x_i - x_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \sum_{i,j=1}^n \tfrac 12 (x_i - x_j)^2 \right]
\end{align}

More generally, what are other good “product of sum” formulas to know? For example, the diagonal/off-diagonal decomposition of a squared sum is useful.

Comment: The first equality involves moving all the $\sum$ symbols to the left hand side and then rewriting them as a single symbol

Comment: And the first expression is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-x_j) \right)^2 \right]$ while the third is $\displaystyle \frac{n}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \left[  (x_i-x_j) ^2 \right] $

Comment: Thanks! Where does the $n/2$ come in though? I’m stuck on that

Comment: I get the $n$ so it’s just the $1/2$ that is giving me troubke